# How to combine SQL rows to single rows and group certain column data into same cell to prepare for flask table rendering using sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, flask

My goal is to render a grid like this in Flask and when the user hovers the cells with "Fail" a popup should appear with all problems detected during a certain time period.

| Server name | Device Offline | Server offline |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Server A | Pass | Pass |
| Server B | Fail | Fail |

In my database, I have a table of servers and a table of problems. The Server ID column links the server table to the foreign key of the problems table.

So when I run a query like this:

```
SELECT servers.id, servers.name, problems.timestamp, problems.category, problems.status problems.description FROM servers LEFT JOIN problems ON servers.id = problems.id
```

I get data like this:

```
438bedc6-1c7a-4527-aa82-2ac183655b6e    Server A    2022-03-19 12:55    server offline  Pass No problem
438bedc6-1c7a-4527-aa82-2ac183655b6e    Server A    2022-03-19 13:55    device offline  Pass No problem
d2bd2d8a-1d84-394c-835c-f0ff274255a2    Server B    2022-03-19 14:55    server offline  Fail Network glitch
d2bd2d8a-1d84-394c-835c-f0ff274255a2    Server B    2022-03-19 14:55    device offline  Fail Device restarted
d2bd2d8a-1d84-394c-835c-f0ff274255a2    Server B    2022-03-19 16:55    server offline  Fail Server restarted
```

As I think I need to render the html table row by row, this becomes a problem as there will be two rows of Server A and three rows of Server B.

Is there a way to combine the data in a way that I get something like this:

```
438bedc6-1c7a-4527-aa82-2ac183655b6e    Server A    2022-03-19 12:55    server offline  Pass  No problem device offline Pass No problem
d2bd2d8a-1d84-394c-835c-f0ff274255a2    Server B    2022-03-19 14:55    server offline  Fail 'Network glitch and Server restarted' device offline fail Device restarted
```

What I want to do in Flask is then to run something like this to render the table and the popup that will appear on hover on a cell that has the status Fail.

```
{% for row in servers %}
                        <tr>
                            <td class="has-details">{{ row.servername }}</td>
                            {% if 'Pass' in row.serverofflinestatus %}
                            <td class="has-details has-background-success"></td>
                            {% else %}
                            <td class="has-details has-background-danger">
                                <article class="details message is-danger">
                                    <div class="message-header">
                                        <p>Problems</p>
                                        <button class="delete" aria-label="delete"></button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="message-body">
                                        <time datetime="2021-10-13">2021-10-13 14:33</time>
                                        <p>{{ row.serverofflinecomments }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </article>
                            </td>
                            {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function `GROUP_CONCAT()` to combine properly the columns of the table `problems`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT id, 
         MIN(timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY id, category, status) timestamp, 
         category, 
         status, 
         GROUP_CONCAT(description, ' and ') OVER (PARTITION BY id, category, status ORDER BY timestamp) description,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, category, status ORDER BY timestamp DESC) rn1,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id, category, status) count
  FROM problems
)
SELECT s.id, s.name, t.timestamp, t.result
FROM servers s 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT id, timestamp, result
  FROM (
    SELECT id, 
           MIN(timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY id) timestamp, 
           GROUP_CONCAT(
             category || ' ' || status || ' ' || CASE WHEN count = 1 THEN description ELSE QUOTE(description) END, '  ') OVER (
             PARTITION BY id 
             ORDER BY timestamp
           ) result,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp DESC) rn2
    FROM cte
    WHERE rn1 = 1
  )
  WHERE rn2 = 1
) t 
ON t.id = s.id;
```

Note that in case there are duplicate timestamps for the same server then the results may be concatenated in different order.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=4168f0a89b5679d047124287087ba01e).